# what does BYTES_REVERSED_HI and BYTES_REVERSED_LO in an PE signify

Tags: malware, pe, static-analysis

How can these pe attributes be used to identify malware.

I was going though a paper [link](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/malicious/attributes-malicious-files-33979) at page 10 he mentioned.

"BYTES_REVERSED_HI and BYTES_REVERSED_LO both make ideal candidates as a primary indicator due to the significant detection rate with a low false positive rate"

Comment: Please share your hypothesis and reasoning, as well as the relevant research you have done.

Comment: let me google this for you https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format

Comment: Can you help with why does some malware has this flag set?

Comment: that paper describes a statistical analysis of differences between two sets of  binaries the flags are set by linker and i don't think a define or switch exist to set them while compiling so i am not sure about the reasoning behind that assertion

Comment: I don't understand the hostility in the responses here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think this is a good and valid question.

And I think the answer here is - it is because it is. What I mean is that they analyzed a bunch of samples, separated them into malicious/benign, and then found out that when these flags are set it's almost always malware, so it makes a good indicator because they observed it to be a good one.

I can't think of a logical reason. It's probably a field nobody sets on purpose in legit software. Maybe some packers or whatever sets the field in order to alter the files' checksum? Google says those flags are obsolete so setting them should not have any effect at all, but it would change a file's checksum.